# Matplotlib matshow a matrix heatmap with 1 dimension being much bigger than the other

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib matshow to show a matrix of `N*F`. Where `N` can be a very large number like `5000` but `F` is only `10` or `100`.

When using matshow, this results in in the `F` dimension getting collapsed because it tries to show rows and columsn with equal amount of space.

I would like the resulting matshow image to have its rows widened while also having its columns shrunk.

Here's an example of the matrix I'm rendering:

[image: Original Image]

I'd like to be able to see the actual rows by stretching it out. The width can however be collapsed, since I'm looking at the overall pattern of the heatmap of the matrix.

What do I need to do the below code so that I can see the rows. Changing the figsize isn't good enough because I don't know exactly how much data I'm going to see, and after testing different figsizes, the resulting heatmap is still collapsed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1
from typing import List, Iterator, Optional

def paint_features(
    matrix: np.ndarray,
    labels: Optional[List[str]] = None,
    title: Optional[str] = None,
    fig: Optional[plt.Figure] = None,
) -> None:
    # change so classes are vertical
    matrix = matrix.T
    if fig is None:
        fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    matrix_image = ax.matshow(matrix, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
    divider = mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="1%", pad=0.05)
    fig.colorbar(matrix_image, cax=cax)
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', bottom=False, labelbottom=False)
    if labels:
        assert len(labels) == matrix.shape[1]
        ax.set_yticklabels([""] + labels)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
    if title is not None:
        fig.suptitle(title)
    fig.tight_layout()


def show_features(
    matrix: np.ndarray, labels: Optional[List[str]] = None, title: Optional[str] = None
) -> None:
    with plt_figure() as fig:
        paint_features(matrix, labels, title, fig)
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `imshow` with `aspect='auto'` to have the plot automatically resize to the axis:

```
aa = np.random.random(size=(5, 500))
plt.imshow(aa, aspect='auto')

# equivalent:
# plt.matshow(aa, fignum=0, aspect='auto')
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: @CMCDragonkai check my edit. You need `fignum=0` or `matshow` will create a new figure with a different aspect ratio